# C++ list of objects not working properly

Tags: c++, oop, casting

UML Diagram : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajsVQ.png

My OOP teacher said that we could implement something like in the above diagram in C++ (for a lab assignment). She said we could do something like this so we wouldn't need two List classes (one for Books and one for Clients).

I started implementing it and i'm stuck on getFromPosition(int) (it is supposed to return the object at certain position in the list). What I am trying to do is to save a Book object in a List object (this works fine) and i would later like to be able to return/read/modify these saved Book objects.It returns the object , but then I (probably) should make a cast of some sort so I could use the methods of the Book. Is this even possible? 
This is the code for the method:

```
   Obj List::getFromPosition(int i){
            return list[i];
        }
```

I hope I gave enough info (this is my first question ).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does NOT work? Has your teacher taught you about template classes and generics?

Comment: Why would you not want two lists? Maybe to preserve the order objects were added, so you can process them the same way. Can't think why else you'd go to the trouble.

Comment: I just realised, you don't want to implement the list class for Books, and the list class for Clients. As @Greg says, templates are the way to go. I guess though that you're being given problems which aren't satisfactorily solved, and later you'll find better ways. It's a bit strange though to introduce the idea that heterogeneous is more acceptable than homogeneous, or that inheritance is appropriate when no useful or common interface is being inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're returning an `Obj` by value, I'm guessing internally you hold a collection of `Obj` objects, and not pointers.

Which is wrong. You run into **object slicing**.

Firstly, you should keep pointers or smart pointers internally, and return an `Obj*` or a `SmartPtr<Obj>`.

Second, whether you need the cast or not depends.

If you have a common method between your deriving classes, it should probably go in the base class. If not, you probably need a cast.

Here's how I'd do it *rough cut*:

```
class List
{
   std::vector<Obj*> _objects;
public:
   Obj* getFromPosition(int i)
   {
      return _objects[i];
   }
};

//...
List list;
//...
Obj* obj = list.getFromPosition(0);

obj->commonMethod();   //common method is virtual and a member of Obj
(dynamic_cast<Book*>(obj))->bookMethod(); //book method is only available for Book class
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your function return a `Book`.

Comment: What if `list[i]` is a client?

Comment: Should he really keep Books and Clients in a same list?